# Can I safely copy an fpos_t?

Tags: c, file, object

I am working on a log file processing program and have defined a structure as follows to allow storing some useful information for parsing the files

```
struct File
{
    FILE* fp;                   // File pointer
    char fname[FILENAME_MAX];   // The file name
    char mode[4];               // File mode (Only use binary modes 'rb', 'ab', 'wb', 'rb+', 'ab+', 'wb+')
    fpos_t pos;                 // A saved position in the file
    fpos_t LineStart;           // Position of the start of the line the file pointer is currently on
    long LineNum;               // Line number the pointer is currently on
};
```

I set the `File` structure members when I open the file, and update them as I work with the file. I would like to use the following functions to save and restore the state of the file

```
void SaveFilePos(struct File *Source, struct File *Save)
{
    [snip]
    Save->LineStart = Source->LineStart;
    if (fgetpos(Source->fp, Save->pos) != 0)
    {
        Ferr("file.c:SaveFilePos():fgetpos() failed");
    }
    [snip]
}

void SetFilePos(struct File *Dest, struct File *Save)
{
    [snip]
    Dest->LineStart = Save->LineStart;
    if (fsetpos(Dest->fp, Save->pos) != 0)
    {
        Ferr("file.c:SetFilePos():fsetpos() failed");
    }
    [snip]
}
```

I check that the file name and mode are the same before restoring a file state.

My question is whether I can safely and portably use `Save->LineStart = Source->LineStart` and `Dest->LineStart = Save->LineStart` to save and restore an `fpos_t` object?

Comment: You're not worried about changes to the file between saving and restoring the position? Say... you save the position when the file has 20 lines, then delete a few lines (from outisde) and restore to an invalid position???

Comment: No. This is an offline analysis. And no data will ever be deleted from a file. It is purely data extraction from files into other files. Only whole files will be deleted

Answer (score 2):

> ... whether I can safely and portably use `Save->LineStart = Source->LineStart` and `Dest->LineStart = Save->LineStart` to save and restore an `fpos_t` object?

You can. The C standard, section Library - Input/output `<stdio.h>` says:

*... `fpos_t` which is a complete object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information needed to specify uniquely every position within a ﬁle.*

A complete object type other than an array type can be copied by assignment.